# PDF thumbnail creation without Imagick or Ghostscript

Tags: php, pdf, thumbnails, ghostscript, imagick

I have a website in a very strict hosting company, they haven't imagick or ghostscript installed and won't let me install and I need to generate a thumbnail from the first page of a PDF file.

Anyone know any class or something that could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MihaiStancu As far as I know GD only works with images, not pdf. :(

Comment: So what **IS** installed on your hosted system?!?! If you can't install additional software, you'll have to work with what you got. And if there's nothing to get your job done -- you'll have to live with it...

Comment: The answer is simple - change hosts.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle The basics... Apache, Php, MySql etc.

Comment: @Bonzo Not that simple, the website is from one of my clients, i tried, really tried to make him change the host, but he won't...

Comment: I can understand your problem as I have been there.